# Unable to see QConsole typeahead suggestions in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

I'm unable to see typeahead suggestions in MarkLogic query console.
It is similiar to intellisense to auto-complete the functions/expressions.
How do I enable the typeahead suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typeahead suggestions is a feature added in MarkLogic 9 - make sure you're running that version.

Comment: Well I am using MarkLogic 8. Thanks Tamas! :)